# Intermittent connection drops on Win 8.1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, ethernet, network-adapter

This is a laptop system. I currently have an issue where my network connection will drop intermittently for anywhere between 5-15 seconds at a time. This is enough to disconnect me from anything I'm doing at the moment. It happens semi-randomly, with only one pattern to it. It seems to drop whenever I'm playing online games, and using a lot of bandwidth. As an example, I could be playing Planetside 2 or Firefall, and standing around in a low populated area and I would get a disconnect for 5 seconds maybe every 30-60 minutes. Once I travel to an area with a lot of players/enemies moving about I may get disconnected every 5 minutes.

So far, I've taken many troubleshooting steps. First, I've talked with my ISP techs, and made some local tests with the modem/router to ensure the problem wasn't with the modem/router or my service. I've narrowed the issue to my laptop's connection to the modem/router.I've tried both the ethernet and wireless connections. The wireless connection drops less frequently than the wired connection, but still drops occasionally. I've tried disabling power management to no avail on both interfaces and changing the DNS to google servers. I've tried 3 different ethernet cables for the ethernet, same behavior on each. I've updated all of my drivers through multiple versions for both interfaces with no effect.

My ethernet nic is a Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller, while my wireless nic is a Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260.

My only ideas at the moment are either a Windows 8.1 issue, two faulty drivers, two faulty NICs, or perhaps an overheating issue. My question is, would overheating cause a NIC to drop connection like this? It seems like it would be possible since I do a lot of gaming on this laptop, which has two SLI GFX cards in it, and the problem manifests itself most often when the system is under load.

DOes anyone here have any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Is there any more information I could provide to help diagnose it?